# can we expose two methods in same class java as a web service using jax-ws with Eclipse?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, myeclipse

I am using myEclipse to develop jax-ws web services. Is it possible to expose two methods from the same class as one web service? if yes how this will affect the WSDL?  Or I have to expose one web service, I mean one wsdl for each method?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how MyEclipse is relevant here.

Yes, you can certainly have more than one method annotated with @WebMethod in a webservice (a class annotated with @WebService).

Yes your WSDL will change to account for the new method you added.

**UPDATE** You asked for examples of a WSDL with multiple soap operations. Here is [one](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Apache+CXF+Tutorial+-+Building+JAX-WS,+JAXB+and+JPA-based+web+service+with+Apache+CXF,+Spring+and+Hyperjaxb3).

Comment: can you please show me an example of WSDL file holding two methods so I will try to modify my generated WSDL file with Eclipse manually.

Comment: could you help me in my question as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080890/wsdl-not-created-in-eclipse